# HTC Android device mounted as USB drive is read-only unless I'm root

Tags: usb, android

When I connect my HTC Incredible S to my Ubuntu 10.10 system as a USB drive, the device seems to mount OK, but is read-only unless I access it as root. For example, if I run `nautilus`, I can't drag and drop files to the SD-card in the phone, but if I run `sudo nautilus` I can.

I have USB debug support set on the phone (`Applications > Development > USB debugging`) and I have added a rule for the device in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` on my Ubuntu system. Any suggestions as to how I can mount the drive so that I can copy content to the SD card without needing to sudo?

**Update**

Following advice from waltinator, I added the following line to my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=3537-3834 /media/usb1 vfat rw,user,noexec,nodev,nosuid,noauto
```

However, the Android device is still being auto-mounted on /media/usb1 with uid and gid root.

**Update 2**

syslog output:

```
Nov 21 23:38:40 rowan-15 usbmount[4352]: executing command: mount -tvfat -osync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime /dev/sdd1 /media/usb1
Nov 21 23:38:40 rowan-15 usbmount[4352]: executing command: run-parts /etc/usbmount/mount.d
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the UUID of the Android, with `sudo blkid`, then add a line to `/etc/fstab` that looks like:

```
UUID=<from above>  <mount point>  <type>  rw,users,noexec,nodev,nosuid,noauto
```

You can find out the  of filesystem the Android has by issuing `mount` while it is plugged in. `man mount` will explain the options.

**New method**: Plug in your Android, hit **F1** in the automounted and opened Nautilus window, to bring up the "Ubuntu Desktop Guide", search for the article "**Open an application when you plug in a device**" - it will show you how to open NO application when you plug in your device. It still gets automounted, in spite of `noauto` for me.

Comment: Duh! You can find out the **type** of the filesystem ...

Comment: OK, I tried this and it's not working. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `noauto` flag should mean that the device doesn't automount when it's connected, right? That's not happening though - it still gets mounted on `/mount/usb1` a few seconds after connecting the USB cable. Part of the problem, I think, is that I don't properly understand how Ubuntu handles these USB devices. Pointers to any documentation I should be reading would be welcome.

Comment: "I tried this and it's not working" contains insufficient detail. What did you do, what was the computer's response, how does this differ from what you expected?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear. As I wrote in my edits to the question, I added a line to `/etc/fstab` based on your suggestion. As I understand the `noauto` flag, this means that connecting the device to the USB cable should no longer automount the file system, but the `user` flag should mean that I can mount it manually without sudo. However, the automount still happens, and the file system is mounted with uid and gid `root`.

Comment: Check the man page for mount (`man mount`), and look for "Mount options for <type>", will it let you specify "UID=" and "GID="?

Comment: And, try the standard trick: Plug in your Android, touch nothing until the system finishes automounting, then type `ls -lrt /var/log`. For each of the "most recently updated" (last in the `ls -lrt` output) files, do a `sudo tail -n 25`. and `dmesg | tail -n 25`. Can you find out what's doing the automount?

Comment: OK, so it's `usbmount` that's doing the automount (see syslog output in updated question, above). `man usbmount` tells me nothing, however.

Comment: I already tried setting the `uid` and `gid` in `/etc/fstab`, but it didn't change the mounted volume permissions. However, in response to your suggestion on checking the logs, it seems that usbmount is getting in before mount, which would explain why not.

Comment: I don't have `usbmount` installed, but `apt-cache search usbmount` says  
    "usbmount - automatically mount and unmount USB mass storage devices"  

so `dpkg -L usbmount` (to see what's in the package to investigate) or `sudo apt-get remove usbmount` (remove the package) should help.